# QQ OAuth error code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I'm trying to use the QQ (Huge Chinese social network similar to ICQ) API which uses OAuth. I'm reasonably familiar with OAuth, but I can only read Chinese via Google Translate.

I use Rails 3.0.7 and follow the instructions in the [oauth gem documentation](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/).

According to the [QQ documentation](http://wiki.opensns.qq.com/wiki/%E3%80%90QQ%E7%99%BB%E5%BD%95%E3%80%91%E8%AF%B7%E6%B1%82%E4%B8%B4%E6%97%B6token) their APP ID corresponds to oauth_consumer_key and their APP KEY is the oauth consumer secret. They also specify which URL's to use. So I do the following in the console:

```
@consumer=OAuth::Consumer.new("APP ID", "APP SECRET",{:site =>
"http://openapi.qzone.qq.com", :request_token_path=>"/oauth/qzoneoauth_request_token", 
:authorize_path => "/oauth/qzoneoauth_authorize", :access_token_path => 
"/get_access_token.php"} )
```

That returns:

```
#<OAuth::Consumer:0x0000010283f6a0 @key="APP ID", @secret="APP SECRET", 
@options={:signature_method=>"HMAC-SHA1", 
:request_token_path=>"/oauth/qzoneoauth_request_token", 
:authorize_path=>"/oauth/qzoneoauth_authorize", 
:access_token_path=>"/get_access_token.php", :proxy=>nil, :scheme=>:header, 
:http_method=>:post, :oauth_version=>"1.0", :site=>"http://openapi.qzone.qq.com"}>
```

Now it's time to get a request token from the server:

```
@request_token=@consumer.get_request_token
```

Unfortunately this returns an error code: `12005` meaning invalid url (thanks @timon-vonk). But what's wrong with it and how do I debug this? Here's a few more details about the request, obtained with [net-http-spy](http://rubygems.org/gems/net-http-spy):

```
@request_token=@consumer.get_request_token(
:oauth_callback => "http://ishiyou.com/qq")          
opening connection to openapi.qzone.qq.com...opened
<- "GET /oauth/qzoneoauth_request_token HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: 
OAuth gem v0.4.4\r\nAuthorization: OAuth 
oauth_callback=\"http%3A%2F%2Fishiyou.com%2Fqq\", 
oauth_consumer_key=\"******\", 
oauth_nonce=\"gpv3iaYb7K3tExGxxnW5bjkyvU6ms3EuL9roLwgxs4\", 
oauth_signature=\"3tgryVqRFjxoXSxnYTO%2FXuRNAU4%3D\", 
oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"1306933000\", 
oauth_version=\"1.0\"\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: openapi.qzone.qq.com\r\n\r\n"
-> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Server: QZHTTP-2.13\r\n"
-> "Date: Wed, 01 Jun 2011 12:56:42 GMT\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 17\r\n"
-> "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
-> "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
reading 17 bytes...
-> "error_code=12005\n"
read 17 bytes
Conn close
```

Answer (score 0):

A 12005 error is usually an invalid URL.

Invalid in the sense that the URL generated is not valid, not non existent. Check what URL is generated. Also, its possible that QQ just parses the request wrong and doesn't send a 404 but a 12005 for some reason.

Comment: I used [net-http-spy](http://rubygems.org/gems/net-http-spy) to get a better idea of what the request was. See above.